# Set of functions that is not open

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathscr B(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ the set of limited functions that are everywhere discontinuous. Show that X is not open in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.

$\mathscr B(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ denotes the set of all bounded functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

My attempt was to show that the interior of $X$ is empty, but it didn't work. I think to solve this problem we have actually to find some h $\in X$ that is not an interior point of X. I wrote it down what that means, but I'm still nstuck on this problem.

Any hint?

Comment: "limited" should be "bounded". and what topology are you assuming on this space?

Comment: @Melissa...Really you have to be specific about the topology of the space..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x).$$

Consider $f\cdot\chi_{(-\infty,R)}$ for $R$ large.

Comment: In which topology ?

Comment: @MariosGretsas  I'm guessing the sup-norm topology.